# Know a good place to purchase seed data of storenames, addresses, and phone numbers?

Tags: mysql, database, data

I just build a new web app, and I am looking for data to seed it with. Anyone know any good seed data retailers? Or am I missing something and there is a way to do this for free. I am entirely open to scraping, and have built a couple scrapers I enjoyed.

Comment: Do you want real data, or just test data (i.e. fictional)?

Comment: @disguntledGoat , real data

Comment: Hey Trip, have Piers or John answered your question or would you like more information?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the US or Canada [infoUSA](http://www.infousa.com/) is worth checking out. A previous employer used to use them for mailings. You can be very specific with what kinds of business you want and what kind of data is required such as "must have phone number" or must be in X industry" or "must be in business over X years" etc.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.yell.com/robots.txt

Lots of sitemaps in there :)

I haven't downloaded the data and had a look at it, but it might contain usable information.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got the scraping know-how, I would suggest scraping [yell.com](http://www.yell.com) for UK business addresses. Maybe [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com)?

It's worth noting that people don't like their websites being scraped so they may well block you *very* quickly and Google is getting quite passionate about duplicate content (I can't remember the exact term for it) on different sites.